# Checking if a Windows forms scroll bar is scrolled all the way down?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a rich text box which serves as a log. The log automatically scrolls itself down when a new message is appended, which is good. The only problem is when the user wants to view something in the log from before; if a new message is appended, the box automatically scrolls all the way down and prevents the user from seeing anything.
I would like to be able to check if the rich text box is scrolled all the way down, and if it isn't not scroll down.

Currently I can get the scroll position in the virtual text space (SendMessage with EM_GETSCROLLPOS). I can also get scroll bar info with GetScrollBarInfo pinvoke. But how do I figure out what the bottom of the virtual text space is?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouln't it be more intuitive if you check whether the end of the text is in the visible area?

Comment: Sure, but how can you do that?

Comment: Ergh, SendMessage with WM_GETTEXT is all that I remember. Have to dig it out, don't have that at hand right now, sorry, but will try to dig it out today or so.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `vScrollBar` control for your `RichTextBox` and handle its Scroll event

```
    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.Last)
        {
            //scrollbar is all the way down
        }
        else
        {
            //user has scrolled up
        }
    }
```