# Determine when textbox has been scrolled to the end

Tags: c#, vb.net, scroll

During an installation, when I got to the stage of accepting the terms, I discovered that the "Next" button was disabled until I scrolled to the end of the text. Can anyone help with how this is done?
I prefer C# or VB.NET

Comment: See [Get current scroll position from rich text box control?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238729/719186)

Comment: This might be something that you need. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/656863/641123

Comment: any solution about it ? I was wondering how could I disable this button till the user scroll till the end of terms and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

try using `vScrollBar` for `RichTextBox!!`

[this will help you (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) 
[here you have form stack overflow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246169/checking-if-a-windows-forms-scroll-bar-is-scrolled-all-the-way-down)